# Azure WebJob .bat file terminates immediately

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a continuous WebJob that is comprised of an executable compiled using the WebJobs SDK (in other words, runs `host.RunAndBlock()` in `Main()`) and has one simple method named `ProcessQueueMessage()` in the `Functions` class. It's completely boilerplate.

The problem is that I need to include an additional executable file in the package, and its file name will alphabetically come before the primary executable's. I will compile to WebJob1.exe, but I need to have something called MyOtherExecutable.exe in the same deployment directory. According to the [WebJobs documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs), that means MyOtherExecutable.exe wins as the primary executable of the WebJob; *it* will be called instead of WebJob1.exe.

I realize there are documented ways to solve this. I could manually change file names and force my WebJob to compile to a name like 111.exe, but that seems like an awful hack. The alternative, which I interpreted to be the preferred and more graceful method, is to include a .bat file with a single line: `start WebJob1.exe`. Unfortunately, when I do that, the WebJob starts and stops immediately, forever, as you can see:

```
[12/14/2015 07:05:55 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.bat' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[12/14/2015 07:05:55 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[12/14/2015 07:05:55 > fed86c: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\WebJob1\irfufwim.i5t>start WebJob1.exe 
[12/14/2015 07:06:06 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
[12/14/2015 07:06:07 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[12/14/2015 07:06:07 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
(repeat)
```

That's not the behavior I was expecting. I figured the .bat file would run my executable (which never terminates from within) and stay open until I manually end it.

It also doesn't provide this very nice plug into the WebJob that I saw when I queued a message and removed all distracting executables/scripts from the WebJob's deployment directory:

```
[12/14/2015 07:18:22 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[12/14/2015 07:18:25 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Run script 'WebJob1.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[12/14/2015 07:18:25 > fed86c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[12/14/2015 07:18:26 > fed86c: INFO] Found the following functions:
[12/14/2015 07:18:26 > fed86c: INFO] WebJob1.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
[12/14/2015 07:18:26 > fed86c: INFO] Job host started
```

That part where it lists out the functions it found indicates to me that everything's communicating as it ought to. It looks official. I'm concerned that even if I were to get a .bat file to work so I could clearly specify the name of the executable I want to run, the server would "stop there" and not make the appropriate hooks into my functions, if that makes sense. I don't know if the hosting mechanisms are intelligent enough to know they've been bounced from a dumb .bat file over to the real executable.

**Short version of my main question:** if `start WebJob1.exe` is not the correct syntax for a .bat file that should run a continuous WebJobs SDK executable, what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "start" and just invoke WebJob1.exe directly. I'm doing that in one of my WebJobs and it works, including giving me all the console logging you're looking for.

One difference is that I use a `run.cmd` rather than a .bat file, which is the recommended way for using a script file to override startup behavior for an exe. However that should really make no difference in your scenario - the .bat file will also work.

Answer (score 2):

`start` will start a separate process to invoke the command. The parent process will continue its execution unless the `wait`-option is set.

I'm guessing there is nothing in your batch script after `start WebJob1.exe` that blocks the parent process from completing so the Web Job runtime will attempt to restart the continuous job. Either call `WebJob1.exe` directly or use the `wait` option with `start`, i.e. `start /wait WebJob1.exe`.

The Web Job runtime will also execute `.exe`-files. Unless you're doing bootstrapping in the batch script, removing it entirely is also an option.